# Which print is "more" correct?

Tags: python

Under python 3, what would be considered most correct?

**Example 1:**

```
a='bacon'
b='salad'
print("I love {type_a} more than {type_b}".format(type_a=a, type_b=b))
```

or

**Example 2:**

```
a='bacon'
b='salad'
print("I love {} more than {}".format(a, b))
```

This came out because sometimes I see myself coding with both given examples, but i'm not really sure what would be the most correct way to use it and when it would be more appropriate to use `.format(type_a=a)` instead of `.format(a)`

Comment: More importantly stick to either single or double quotes across your whole code. And use whatever makes your code easier to read and understand, not what someone considers "more correct", and that points to the former, not latter.

Comment: The first form may be preferred if you had to remove the string from its context (e.g. if you have to give the string to a translator).

Comment: The second is preferred, first when the second is unclear or cannot be expressed in the second form.

Comment: @josten i totally aggre with you, but i would like to  have only 2+1 or 1+2 on my project instead both :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first form is more appropriate if you anticipate using different languages, since the order of the words in the sentence may need to be different. Or if your substitutions are coming from a dictionary.

The second form is shorter and more direct. It's the one I'd prefer unless I had a reason to choose otherwise.

Comment: I'm on the track then, Thanks everyone for replying

Comment: @Thales They are identical in output, but one substitutes using keywords and the other replaces in order of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

They are both nearly identical, except in the first one you can rearrange the order of the variables passed in, and the second one takes the variables in the order they are passed in.

Comment: True, but sometimes the example two destroys my effort to keep the 78 columns limit.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you just want to print something like this : "`var1, var2, var3, ...`", no matter what form you use. Its only a question of style an length: in one hand, the first example is more explicit, but on the other hand it takes more place, could need a new line, which is less visible generally.

But where the first form remains useful is when you have something like "`var1 var2 var1 var3 var1`". Then, you've got two solutions, too:

```
# 1
print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(var1, var2, var1, var3, var1))
# 2
print("{v1} {} {v1} {} {1}".format(var2, var3, v1=var1))
```

The second solution is in general better, but the need to write key-worded arguments in last can lead to several errors.